# best way to run string functions over returned database object

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I need to run various string functions over the data returned from the database before I send it to the view using Laravel 5.3.  Basic stuff like str_replace().

Now maybe there's a good way to setup Accessors on my model and somehow use the model on the landing page but I thought I would go a different route and just do this one query manually outside of the model.

So I have a view provider that successfully gets my data into the view.  It looks like this:

```
class ViewLandingProvider extends ServiceProvider {
   public function boot() {
    // process when featured homepage element is present...
    View::composer('mybladetemplate', function ($view){

        $featuredProperties = DB::table('properties')
            ->where([
                ['featured_property', '=', '1'],
                ['supplier_id', '=', 123],
            ])
            ->orderBy('prop_id', 'desc')
            ->limit(6)
            ->get();

        // run str_replace!
        $featuredProperties->each(function($property){
            $property->prop_url=str_replace("http://domain.com/","http://www.domain.com/",$property->prop_url);
        });

        View::share('featuredProperties', $featuredProperties);
    });
  }
}
```

this then loops within a view and it all works nicely

```
 @if(isset($featuredProperties))
     @foreach ($featuredProperties as $property)
         <li>
             <a title="{{ $property->prop_name }}" href="{{ $property->prop_url }}"></a>
         </li>           
    @endforeach
@endif
```

As you can see in the example above, I have str_replace() running over the data collection using ->each() and that's working to let me do a simple string replacement that I need to undertake.

Being Laravel though, I'm sure there's some magic that could be pulled here to do this more intelligently.

So is there a way in the actual database request code that I can specify that a certain column to be returned should automatically have a function run over it ?

Just to clarify, I want to make these changes in the provider php rather than the view file and I want to do this outside of a model with Accessors.

Comment: Just use your model and create an accessor as you pointed out.
It’s the simplest, the easiest and the proper way to do something like this.
It's not a big deal to have such accessors to a model, even if you tend to use them rarely. The reason is that you want all of your model related stuff to actually be inside your model for better maintenance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you may be looking for a collection macro.  You would register it in your `AppServiceProvider` like:

```
Collection::macro('formatPropUrl', function() {

    return collect($this->items)->map(function($property) {
        $property->prop_url=str_replace("http://domain.com/","http://www.domain.com/",$property->prop_url);

        return $property;
    });

});
```

Then for your query you could do:

```
$featuredProperties = DB::table('properties')
    ->where([
        ['featured_property', '=', '1'],
        ['supplier_id', '=', 123],
    ])
    ->orderBy('prop_id', 'desc')
    ->limit(6)
    ->get()
    ->formatPropUrl();
```

Comment: Excellent @Eric!  Thanks for sharing.   There's not so much about this on the web so great to publicise this method some more.

Answer (score 5):

You can write select query as:

```
$featuredProperties = DB::table('properties')
    ->where([
        ['featured_property', '=', '1'],
        ['supplier_id', '=', 123],
    ])
    ->select('*', DB::raw("replace(prop_url, 'http://domain.com/', 'http://www.domain.com/') as new_prop_url"))
    ->orderBy('prop_id', 'desc')
    ->limit(6)
    ->get();
```

And then in your view, you can do as:

```
@if(isset($featuredProperties))
   @foreach ($featuredProperties as $property)
       <li>
           <a title="{{ $property->prop_name }}" href="{{ $property->new_prop_url }}"></a>
       </li>           
  @endforeach
@endif
```

Comment: I was about to suggest the same, go for Raw SQL if it's just to do a simple replace. Althought @Patricus seems to have a real good answer there, and if you are learning Laravel why not go for it and start using the full power of it?

Comment: I will upvote this since this satisfies what the OP asks.

Answer (score 2):

This would be a good use case for the Presenter pattern. There are a few Laravel packages out there to help with this, but the most up-to-date one looks to be [mccool/laravel-auto-presenter](https://github.com/laravel-auto-presenter/laravel-auto-presenter).

The idea behind the package is that you would create a `Presenter` object, which wraps the `Model` that needs to display information. The `Presenter` object contains all the logic for any data transformations required by the view.

This is untested, but an example implementation is shown below. Create an `app\Presenters` directory, and add the following file:

**app\Presenters\PropertyPresenter.php**

```
namespace App\Presenters;

use App\Property;
use McCool\LaravelAutoPresenter\BasePresenter;

class PropertyPresenter extends BasePresenter
{
    // this parameter MUST be named $resource
    public function __construct(Property $resource)
    {
        $this->wrappedObject = $resource;
    }

    // create functions for any properties you'd like to present
    public function prop_url()
    {
        return str_replace("http://domain.com/", "http://www.domain.com/", $this->wrappedObject->prop_url);
    }

    // you can also create functions for properties that don't actually
    // exist on the model. in view, access via $property->secure_prop_url
    public function secure_prop_url()
    {
        return str_replace("http:", "https:", $this->prop_url);
    }
}
```

Now, you need to modify your `Property` model to tell it about its presenter. It will need to implement the `HasPresenter` interface and define the `getPresenterClass()` method.

```
namespace App;

use App\Presenters\PropertyPresenter;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use McCool\LaravelAutoPresenter\HasPresenter;

class Property extends Model implements HasPresenter
{
    public function getPresenterClass()
    {
        return PropertyPresenter::class;
    }
}
```

Finally, all this logic depends on actually accessing the `Property` model inside the view. Your current logic is using `DB::table('properties')`, which will create an `Collection` of `stdClass` objects. This needs to be changed to actually use your `Property` model, so your view will get a `Collection` of `Property` models.

```
class ViewLandingProvider extends ServiceProvider {
    public function boot() {
        // process when featured homepage element is present...
        View::composer('mybladetemplate', function ($view) {

            $featuredProperties = \App\Property::where([
                    ['featured_property', '=', '1'],
                    ['supplier_id', '=', 123],
                ])
                ->orderBy('prop_id', 'desc')
                ->limit(6)
                ->get();

            View::share('featuredProperties', $featuredProperties);
        });
    }
}
```

Your view will not need to change at all.

Comment: Thanks for this patricus but I wanted to do this without a model being present and this relies on one right ?

Comment: @AdamJones Why specifically avoid using Models?  There's a _lot_ of benefit that can come from using typed objects.

Comment: I know but it's for data that would only be used on one page and nowhere else.  As I'm learning Laravel I know this kind of situation will arise again sometimes where I just need something that is editable via a db but it's just some snippet of text that appears only in one place.

Answer (score 2):

Best way to replace string in query is to user sql `replace` function. When working with large data sets there is performance issue to replace strings with php. Laravel has handy way to extend the build in `Builder` so you don't have to write raw queries. Here is an example how to do it.

```
<?php

namespace App\Providers;

use Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;

class AppServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    /**
     * Bootstrap any application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function boot()
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Register any application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function register()
    {
        Builder::macro('replace', function ($column, $searchText, $replaceText)
        {
            return $this->addSelect(DB::raw("replace($column, '$searchText', '$replaceText') as $column"));
        });


 }
}
```

With this `Macro` registered on the query builder your query will look like this.

```
$featuredProperties = DB::table('properties')
            ->where([
                ['featured_property', '=', '1'],
                ['supplier_id', '=', 123],
            ])
            ->replace('prop_url', 'http://domain.com/', 'http://www.domain.com/')
            ->orderBy('prop_id', 'desc')
            ->limit(6)
            ->get();
```

Comment: I like this solution a lot better than mine 

Answer (score 1):

The `get()` method of `Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder` returns an instance of `Illuminate\Support\Collection`. This class offers many methods for manipulating a collection of data.

You can learn about it more in the [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/collections).

Comment: Hi Doom5 thanks for putting me in the right direction.  I've looked into this this and am still a little lost.    Doesn't the get method return just a part of an object ?  Or can I parse the whole data object to it and then filter by key within a loop somehow ?